# Travis CI, deploy to 2 apps based on tags

Tags: travis-ci

desired goal (psuedo code)

```
if (tag) { deploy to live-app}
else { deploy to test-app}
```

things I've tried:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  app: live-app
  api_key:
    secure: ...

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  app: test-app
  on: 
    tags: true
    all_branches: true # needed due to travis limitation, we deploy only on master
  api_key:
    secure: ...
```

this results in travis ignoring the first deploy setup to the test app.

any ideas?

I know I can write my own script to do that, just wondering if there's a cleaner "travisy" solution since this sounds to me like a pretty common scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
deploy:
    - provider: heroku
      app: live-app
      api_key:
        secure: ...
      on:
        tags: false

    - provider: heroku
      app: test-app
      on: 
        tags: true
        all_branches: true # needed due to travis limitation, we deploy only on master
      api_key:
      secure: ...
```